# Adding drop down menu to plotly line graph with R

Tags: r, plotly, dropdown

I am looking to add a dropdown feature to a plotly graph which will highlight a chosen id variable and will make the selected id's line change to a different color. An example of a code to produce the type of chart I'm considering is

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
set.seed(2001)

## make 10 random data series
data <- data.frame(
  t = rep(1:50, 10),
  id = sort(rep(1:10, 50)),
  y = rnorm(500)
 )

## cumulate the random variates by group
data <- data %>%
 group_by(id) %>% 
 mutate(y2 = cumsum(y))

## plot 
plot <- data %>% 
 plot_ly(x = ~ t, y = ~y2, text = ~id) %>% 
 add_lines(split = ~id, color = I('gray'), alpha = 0.5) %>% 
 hide_legend() 
plot
```

What I'm looking to do is create a drop down selection choice so that I can select say id = 3, and change that line corresponding to id = 3 to blue, keeping all others as gray. I found how to change overall styles with dropdowns, but couldn't find this specific question. Thanks in advance.

Andrew